# Error in face recognition while creating training data

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, machine-learning, face-recognition

I am referring to this video to create the training model.

**[Unlock Your Application With Your Face using OpenCV]**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXYJUrpQgzg

**[Github link]**
https://github.com/krishnaik06/Unlock-Application/blob/master/Face%20Recognition%20%E2%80%93%20Unlock%20Your%20Computer%20With%20Your%20Face!%20-%20Copy.ipynb
but I am getting an error while executing it. Please help

**here's the code:**

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

#Load HAAR face classifier

face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

#Load functions
def face_extractor(img):
   #Function detects faces and returns the cropped face
   #If no face detected, it returns the input image

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    if faces is ():
        return None

   #Crop all faces found
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cropped_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    return cropped_face

 #Initialize Webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count = 0

#Collect 100 samples of your face from webcam input
while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if face_extractor(frame) is not None:
        count += 1
        face = cv2.resize(face_extractor(frame), (200, 200))
        face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #save file in specified directory with unique name
        file_name_path = './faces/user/' + str(count) + '.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(file_name_path, face)

     #Put count on images and display live count
        cv2.putText(face, str(count), (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Face Cropper', face)
    
    else:
        print("Face not found")
        pass

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13 or count == 100: #13 is the Enter Key
        break
    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()      
print("Collecting Samples Complete")
```

**expected output**->Collecting Samples Complete

**my output**->

```
'''
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f1001ab36732> in <module>
     31     ret, frame = cap.read()
     32     print(type(frame))
---> 33     if face_extractor(frame) is not None:
     34         count += 1
     35         face = cv2.resize(face_extractor(frame), (200, 200))

<ipython-input-1-f1001ab36732> in face_extractor(img)
     11 
     12     gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
---> 13     faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
     14 
     15     if faces is ():

error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-cff9bdsm\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

'''

Comment: so what should I do now? I am new to programming, please help

Comment: To debug this, it helps to show what `for (x,y,w,h) in faces:` is giving you. Print that, and you might find something interesting.

Comment: `for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
cropped_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
return cropped_face 
`
This function is used in that video.@DaveW.Smith

Comment: I think the problem in the path. Try giving the full path for instance: `face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/opencv/data/Haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')` Otherwise there is no issue with the code.
`

Answer (score 0):

first go to files and create new-> Haarcascades->upload the "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
similarly create a new file named faces and then users in it
make sure that cv is installed too this should help you out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).